# ASP.NET get checkbox values to c# method

Tags: javascript, c#, html, asp.net-mvc

I'm pretty unexperienced with asp.net and atm I've got the following html and javascript code at my .cshtml view

```
    <div class="jumbotron">
</div>
<div class="row">
    <h2>Select the records you want to export into an excel sheet.</h2>
    <hr />
    <form name="recordSelection" method="POST" action="" >
        <p>Press the "Download" button after you've selected the needed records.</p>
        <blockquote>
            <input type="checkbox" name="record" value="German Sales Office"/> German Sales Office<br/>
            <input type="checkbox" name="record" value="UK Sales Office"/> UK Sales Office<br/>
            <input type="checkbox" name="record" value="France Sales Office"/> France Sales Office<br/>
            <input type="checkbox" name="record" value="Spain Sales Office"/> Spain Sales Office<br/>
            <input type="checkbox" name="record" value="Hoofddorp Office"/> Hoofddorp Office<br/>
            <input type="checkbox" name="record" value="Brussels Office"/> Brussels Office<br/>
        </blockquote>
        <hr/>
        <input id="dlBttn" name="submitButton" type="submit" value="Download" onclick="GetCheckboxValues();"/>
    </form>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
    function GetCheckboxValues(form) {
        var checkedValues = [];
        var offices = document.getElementsByName('record');
        for (var i = 0; offices[i]; i++) {
            if (offices[i].checked) {
                checkedValues.push(offices[i].value);
            }
        }
    }

</script>
```

I need the values of the checked checkboxes to know which records I have to get from my database and then created an excel sheet with those records. But I don't know how to get those values to my C# code. Any advice of how to call a C# method from my javascript code? Or do I have to create a Controller `ActionResult`or something?

Comment: You have multiple questions 1) How to get checkbox values 2) How to send values to server  and 3) How to process values in server. Make sure you edit the question to post 1 question at a time.

Comment: Sry for that but I thought I could post it that way because it all is connected in one process. I guess I get the checkbox values in my "GetCheckboxValues" function but now I don't know how to process further. As you said, get those values from my script to the server for further processing.

Comment: If you don't add onclick client side handler, then all your form would be submitted to the server. Then you can access checkboxes on the server.

Comment: Where are you creating the excel sheet ? I assume it in the server, In that case you need an action method to which this form is posted where you can get the selected checkboxes and generate your excel

Comment: You have a form. When you post that form to a method (say `public ActionResult Export(string[] record)` then the parameter will contain the values of the checked checkboxes. Your script does nothing useful and can be deleted. And you need to specify the `action` attribute in you `<form>` tag. Then you should go to the MVC site and learn the basics of MVC, in particular how to generate a view using the strongly type `HtmlHelper` methods.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my problem with the helpful advices from the comments. I posted the form to the method `public ActionResult ExportData(string[] record)` by specifying the `action` attribute of my form to `action="@Url.Action("ExportData","MyController")"`. To get the checkbox values from client to the server and be able to process with the rest of my code.
(Also deleted the script because it didn't do anything useful)